# SQL Error when I try to update an item using Dapper and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

[Picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwn8J.png)

```
    public bool UpdateDistrict(string name, int id,int primarySeller, string primarySellerName)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string connStr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True";

        string sql = "UPDATE District" + " SET Name = @name, Id = @id, PrimSellerId = @primarySeller , PrimSellerName = @primarySellerName" +
            " WHERE Id = @id";
       var  district=GetDistrict(id);
        if(name==null || name=="")
        {
            name=district.Name;
        }
        

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Query(sql, new
            {
                Name = name,
                Id = id,
                PrimSellerId = primarySeller,
                PrimSellerName = primarySellerName,

            });
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is what I get as error when I try to update in the database

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar
> variable "@primarySeller".

Comment: Try `@PrimSellerName` or change the anonymous parameter object to `primarySeller = primarySeller,`. Side point: You want `conn.Execute` not `conn.Query`. And consider using multiline verbatim strings (by prefixing with `@`) which makes the query more readable

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the comment, when you write a query in SQL:

```
UPDATE District
SET 
  Name = @name, 
  Id = @id, 
  PrimSellerId = @primarySeller , 
  PrimSellerName = @primarySellerName 
WHERE Id = @id
```

It is the parameter names (text after @) that should be specified in the anonymous type passed as the parameter arguments:

```
        new
        {
            name,
            id,
            primarySeller,
            primarySellerName,
        }
```

In your SQL all your parameter names are the same as the c# variable names you use to make the anonymous type, so you can abbreviate the creation of the AT by just mentioning the variable names; the compiler will use them and the property names for the AT unless you're on an old version of .Net that doesn't support this (you'll find out), in which case you'll have to specify the column name too:

```
primarySeller = primarySeller
```

If your names differ you'll need to ensure that the AT property names are matched to the SQL parameter names:

```
  conn.Query(
    "UPDATE t SET userAge = @u WHERE id = @i",
    new { u = 19, i = someId }
  );
```

If you're running an update, insert, delete, merge (most things that aren't a select and don't produce rows of values, use Execute; it returns an integer of the number of rows affected, which you may want to utilise to indicate something didn't save:

```
int r = conn.Execute(...);
return r == 1;
```